# Правка html файла на word-press

Tags: wordpress

Добавляю посты в теме на word-press, а они стоят криво , хочу править их но не могу найти блоки которые содержат пост и соответственно прописать им стили,сам word-press к данным постам добавляет стили в код html, а не в style.css.
прикрепляю скрин. 
помогите разобраться как найти мне и как задать стили. [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

Вам нужно править шаблон Вашей темы. Это можно сделать через админку.
Если Вы не можете сделать этого, убедитесь что у Вас есть права на изменение файлов темы.